# How to keep proper keys in the feed of a SpreadSheet on Google API

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have the following very simple method for retrieving the data from a Spreadsheet as records:

```
List<Map<String, String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
ListFeed feed = spreadsheetService.getFeed(worksheet.getListFeedUrl(), ListFeed.class);
for (ListEntry row : feed.getEntries()) {
    Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<>();
    for (String tag : row.getCustomElements().getTags()) {
        record.put(tag, row.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
    }
    records.add(record);
}
```

However, this `tag` of his is not the proper string I wrote as a header in the table. It seems that the API strips every accent, space, parenthesis and god knows what, and takes every letter to lower case as well, before storing it on the map (just the keys, the values are fine).

So:

1. What exactly does it strip of/keep, and why?
2. How do I prevent it from doing that, or at least workaround it?

So far I've stripped the characters I mentioned of my reference strings when I am retrieving the data. So I did something like:

```
private static String normalize(String key) {
    return StringUtils.stripAccents(key).replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "").toLowerCase();
}
```

But that is bad because:

1. I'm not sure what else is removed by google, so I don't know if it works (since beta I had to add parenthesis and now slashs too to this method)
2. Key conflicts my happen (e.g., 'a sting' == 'as ting', etc)

The names of the columns are user input, and I didn't want to limit my users to use only pretty variable-name-like strings. And I don't want them to have an error because of a key conflict they didn't even known existed. It should be transparent to them.

Ideas?

Comment: Use cellfeed? It does not strip and I don't think there is much speed difference.